# java.util.Date to kotlinx.datetime.LocalDateTime

Tags: kotlin, java.util.date, kotlinx

I have a value of type `java.util.Date` which was obtained from a legacy third-party API. Is there a direct way of converting it to `kotlinx.datetime.LocalDateTime`? I know how to do it only in a roundabout way, such as serializing to String and deserializing, or by converting to `java.time.LocalDateTime` first and then to the wanted type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most efficient conversion would be with `Instant.fromEpochMilliseconds`

Here's an example extension. You can do something similar for other types that you may need

```
import java.util.Date
import kotlinx.datetime.FixedOffsetTimeZone
import kotlinx.datetime.Instant
import kotlinx.datetime.LocalDateTime
import kotlinx.datetime.UtcOffset
import kotlinx.datetime.toLocalDateTime

fun Date.toLocalDateTime(): LocalDateTime =
  Instant.fromEpochMilliseconds(this.time).toLocalDateTime(
    FixedOffsetTimeZone(
      UtcOffset.ZERO
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

i Think the best thing you can do is to convert it to a string and than convert into a `kotlinx.datetime.LocalDateTime`

The problem is that not all java types can be converted directly into a kotlin one especially not with the old DataType `java.util.Date.`

It is also posible with the new DataType `java.time.LocalDateTime`.